# JavaScript on Android 2.3 – "this" not working?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a class that is structured something like this

```
function myClass () {
    this.varA = 0;
}

myClass.prototype.consts = {
    someConst : 1,
    anotherConst : 1000,
}

myClass.prototype.startIt = function () {
    window.setTimeout(this.brokenFunc.bind(this), this.consts.anotherConst);
}

myClass.prototype.brokenFunc = function () {
    this.varA += this.consts.someConst;

    window.setTimeout(this.brokenFunc.bind(this), this.consts.anotherConst); 
}

// Example call
var myObj = new myClass();
myObj.startIt();
```

This works fine on most Android devices -- but a user running Android 2.3 has now informed me that it doesn't work and I could reproduce the error in an emulator. First, it says `TypeError: Result of expression 'this.brokenFunc.bind' [undefined] is not a function` for this line (within `startIt`):

```
window.setTimeout(this.brokenFunc.bind(this), this.consts.anotherConst);
```

Fair enough, I thought, and did the old `var _this = this` trick to get around the `bind` call. But now it says `TypeError: Result of expression 'this.consts' [undefined] is not an object` in this line

```
this.varA += this.consts.someConst;
```

And I'm a little lost. How can this piece of code *not* work? Especially since it works in most Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `setTimeout` invokes functions with `this` of the global object (i.e., `window`, in the browser). (Side note: in strict mode, it's `undefined` instead.) Thus, when you don't use `bind`, the `this` `brokenFunc` is now `window` instead of the object that registered the timeout.

In order to preserve the `this` from `startIt`, you'll need to wrap your call in an anonymous function:

```
myClass.prototype.startIt = function () {
    var that = this;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // call brokenFunc with the outer this
        that.brokenFunc();
    }, this.consts.anotherConst);
}
```

Your first error happened because the Android 2.3 browser doesn't support the EMCAScript 5 `bind` function. Your second error appeared because `this.consts` is really `window.consts`, which doesn't exist. Just wrap the call in an anonymous function that has `that` in its scope, and call the function from `that`.

Comment: Never mind my first comment, I get what you're saying now. I will give this a try, thank you!

Comment: I edited in a bit more explanation, just so everything is 100% clear.

Comment: It still didn't work that way. However, it works if I use `_this.brokenFunc.call(_this);` in the anonymous function. Getting it to work is only one side to it, though. Is this an acceptable (= clean) solution?

Comment: Oops, yes -- `that.brokenFunc()` is what you want. With that change, the `call` isn't necessary (so I've updated my answer accordingly). In terms of the cleanest solution, this isn't too bad. `bind` really is the cleanest way to go; if you want to use that instead, you can use the [`bind` shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) on MDN.

Comment: Thanks, omitting the `call` call and using an anonymous function is what I'll go with. Storing the `this` context wasn't new to me, I just  didn't think far enough to see that I need to wrap it in an anonymous function. Thanks!